# Handlebars email template is not working for express properly

Tags: handlebars.js, nodemailer, amazon-ses, express-handlebars

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const sesTransport = require('nodemailer-ses-transport');
const express = require('express');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.engine('.hbs', exphbs.engine({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    extname: '.hbs',
    layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'layouts'),
    partialsDir: path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'partials')
}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
app.set('views',  path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

    const options = {
    from: 'mailbox@******.in',
    to: '********@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Test email',
    template: 'main',
    context: {
        name: 'John Doe',
        message: 'This is a test email.'
    }
};

     transporter.sendMail(options, function(err, info) {
    console.log(options);
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        console.log(info);
    }
});
```

I am using Node v18.14.2. I am new to use this kind of Template engine for emails. I am getting blank emails when I trigger this one. I know there is something wrong about my configuration. But I cannot figure it out. I got a Type error when I used **app.engine('.hbs', exphbs(conf))** initially So I changed it to **app.engine('.hbs', exphbs.engine(conf))**.

Folder structure is
views-->layouts-->main.hbs

```
"dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/functions-framework": "^3.1.3",
    "archiver": "^5.3.1",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1324.0",
    "axios": "^1.2.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-handlebars": "^6.0.7",
    "mysql2": "^3.0.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.1",
    "nodemailer-express-handlebars": "^6.0.0",
    "nodemailer-ses-transport": "^1.5.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "sequelize": "^6.28.0"
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you trying to use a *local* template with Amazon SES? That's not gonna work. How is node mailer supposed to know, how to render your email body? The handlebars engine with express is used to render the html responses of youf wrbservrr. Either you have to render your template locally and set the html content instead of a template name, or create the respective template in Amazon SES

Comment: I fixed it by this way. Storing the rendered html using callback. res.render('main',{ layout: 'email-template' },  function(err, renderedHtml) {
    if (err) {
     console.log('err')
    } else {html = renderedHtml;  const options = {
       ....
        html:html,
    }; }
  });. Working like a charm. Thanks.